# Is there no solution to display japanese text in google chrome via html

Tags: html

//Is there no solution to display japanese text in google chrome via html other than //dispalying those glyph rectangles and then letting gtranslate to translate it.

//i dont want changes in browser settings. Want changes in code only. here's the code as //simple as it can be

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
</head>
<body>
<h1>ドの再発行パスワ</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wut? Chrome has no problems with Japanese whatsoever. Provide more details about what exactly is happening and what exactly you're doing.

Comment: you see that simple html code. I want to display the text(its japanese) within <h1> tags in chrome. Its possible to display on OS having japanese font. But others will see those rectangles in chrome. rest browsers it works fine

Comment: The code as shown works just fine. Give us a *complete* example including how exactly the result looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show works just fine. There's nothing more you can do from the point of a website author. You give Japanese text properly formatted to the browser, the browser has problems rendering it.

*(You give no real detail in your question, but from the comment thread underneath a now removed answer here it was clear that only **Chrome on Windows XP without Asian language pack installed** has this problem, so the following applies to this very narrow situation.)*

The *platform*, which in this case is the operating system + browser, need to be able to support Japanese text. If they don't, the text won't render. Since Japanese (and Chinese) are somewhat special in requiring support for thousands upon thousands of glyphs, Windows XP and below required a separate language pack to be installed for that support. In later Windows versions this support has mostly been integrated into the base install, supposedly because the increase in size doesn't matter that much any more these days (remember that XP is over a decade old, hard disk sizes were a lot different back then).

If Chrome requires this language pack to be provided by the operating system, then that's the solution. It doesn't come with this support bundled; if you don't like that, contact Google for a fix. In practice this should pretty much be a non-issue though. Anyone who is interested in Japanese web pages and is able to read them and is using Chrome to visit them will very likely already have that pack installed. Because this doesn't just concern *your* site, it concerns *all* web pages. Users will have already solved this problem for themselves if they really needed to.

Comment: You are rite... but see that Internet explorer on the same machine shows all japanese without any language pack.... so i think its better to contact google.... which i think most of us with same problem have already done...

Comment: And I suspect Google doesn't care because 1) there's a perfectly valid solution already available, 2) for most people this will be a non-issue already and 3) frickin' XP is over a frickin' decade old, even Microsoft won't support it anymore in the very near future; get off it already. ;-P